# Oracle SQL - Return rows with a value based on multiple values in a second field

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to return the rows that contain the employee names (in one field) who are **only classified as Managers** (not as Workers, or as Managers and Workers).

Managers and Workers values are in a second field.

So it might look like this:

```
+----------+------------+
| 'Miller' |  'Manager' |
| 'Jones'  |  'Manager' |
| 'Jones'  |  'Worker'  |
+----------+------------+
```

In this instance I just want it to return `'Miller'`.

I can get one or both, but not the ones where an employee is only classified as a Manager.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having min(classification) = max(classification) and min(classification) = 'manager';
```

Answer (score 0):

Method with a subquery which should work well when there are not only 'Managers' and 'Workers' in the table:

```
SELECT t1.name FROM t t1
WHERE
    t1.classification='Manager'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM t t2 WHERE t1.name=t2.name AND t2.classification='Worker'
    )
```

Comment: I removed 'AS' before the table aliases, which is not allowed in Oracle. Only column aliases can be preceded by 'AS'.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of titles. If they have a title of 'Manager' and there's only one title, select the individual:

```
SELECT *
  FROM PEOPLE p
  INNER JOIN (SELECT NAME, COUNT(TITLE) AS TITLE_COUNT
                FROM PEOPLE
                GROUP BY NAME) c
    ON c.NAME = p.NAME
  WHERE p.TITLE = 'Manager' AND
        c.TITLE_COUNT = 1;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2f743b820ed5df1dbf9f65180bc09ba8)